# Laravel sort by average of property of relationship

Tags: laravel

I'm wondering if what I'd like to achieve is possible with Eloquent. Say you have a Post model with a Comments model relationship, and the Comment model has a `votes` property.

I know you can get a Post collection with the Comments count with:

```php
$posts = Post::withCount('comments')->get();
```

And that this is how to apply a votes filter on the relationship:

```php
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function (Builder $q, $vote_count) {
  $q->where('votes', '>=', $vote_count);
});
```

But what I would like to do, ideally in one query, is filter (using `where()`) and sort (using `orderBy()`) the posts collection on an average vote score.

To get that average for *one* `Post` I would first get the sum with `sum('votes')` and divide it by the `withCount('comments')` to get the average.

But I'm wondering if I can make a filter for a *collection*, all in one query, that filters on the average vote score.

Comment: You can get the Post comments votes average with `Post::withCount(['comments as comments_avg_votes' => function($query) { $query->select(DB::raw('avg(votes)')); }])->get();`. But I don't understand what you want to filter

Comment: Thanks. So with your query you now have the average number of votes. On that average I'd like to do 1) a `where` on that average so you can get all the Posts where the average of the votes of the connected comments is bigger than a certain value and 2) a `orderBy` on that average so that you can order the Posts based on the average of the votes of the connected comments.

Comment: Ah, I now see that I can pass `comments_avg_votes` to `where` and `orderBy`, awesome! Feel free to add your comment with that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Last one: the `orderBy` works but the `where` doesn't, it gives an `Unknown column 'comments_avg_votes' in 'where clause' `

Comment: Hey! How are you passing that `where`? Something like this? `Post::withCount(['comments as comments_avg_votes' => function($query) { $query->select(DB::raw('avg(votes)'));  }])->where('comments_avg_votes', '>', $value)->orderByDesc('comments_avg_votes')->get();`

Comment: As I already answered a couple of your questions, I started doing a [sandbox](https://phpsandbox.io/n/red-snowflake-ppkq-onuz9?files=%2Fapp%2FHttp%2FControllers%2FPostController.php) to test and it seems that the `where` works for me

Comment: Thanks for setting this up. This indeed works, so feel free to add it as an answer then I'll accept it. 

It's not working yet for me yet though, probably because I build my query dynamically. I do:
`$posts = Post::query();`
`$posts->withCount(['comments as comments_avg_votes' => function($query) { $query->select(DB::raw('avg(votes)'));  }])`
This works fine. Later on I do:
`$posts->orderBy('comments_avg_votes', 'desc'); // This works`
`$posts->where('comments_avg_votes', '>=', 3); // This doesn't`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Have a look here: https://phpsandbox.io/n/tight-sun-xp7v-avhzq?files=%2Fapp%2FHttp%2FControllers%2FPostController.php. I'm not getting any errors, though it returns a blank page instead of a list of posts.

Comment: You have to access to the `/posts` route in the preview to match that controller function and see the posts list

Comment: I know, there it's blank...

Comment: Did you run the migrations and the seeds? In the sandbox that I gave you, I had made some factories and a seeder to insert random data in the DB, so in the one you created (a fork of that I suppose) you would have to run `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` . Then you can try to remove that `where` to see all the data, in case in that random data, no record meets the condition of the `where`

Comment: Yeah I ran the migrations. And indeed you're right, everything works as expected, I've created a new sandbox here where you can see it does: https://phpsandbox.io/n/late-tooth-0pze-h587a?files=%2Fapp%2FHttp%2FControllers%2FPostController.php. In my own application it doesn't work, so I'll have to figure out why that is as I'm using almost the exact same query and structure... Please feel free to add your suggestion as an answer and I'll accept it, I'll try to figure out more about why it's not working on my end.

Comment: Ok. I added the answer. The only thing I can think of is that there is a difference between the laravel or PHP or MySQL versions.  or as configured

Comment: Yeah it's really strange, I build the query just like in the sandbox that I've mentioned where it works as expected.

Comment: What I now expect is that because the subquery has some `where` clauses the property `comments_avg_votes` doesn't exist on all the instances of the `$posts` collection. I'll look into this more.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ it looks like `comments_avg_votes` is `null` when there are no comments connected. Is it possible to make that value `0` in that case? I think that this is causing the issue?

Comment: Yes, is possible. I'm not on my computer now to test it, but you could use IFNULL or COALESCE. Try `avg(IFNULL(votes, 0)) ` or `avg(COALESCE(votes, 0))`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I've created a new question about this topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68724153/laravel-where-on-average-relationship-column-with-additional-where-clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Post comments votes average passing an array with the relationship name as key and an anonymous function as value. Inside the function you can perform a `selectRaw` querying the `votes` column average. Then you will have available that "column" (an alias actually) to do the `where` and the `orderBy`:

```
$value = 5;
Post::withCount(['comments as comments_avg_votes' => function($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('avg(votes)'));
    }])
    ->where('comments_avg_votes', '>', $value)
    ->orderByDesc('comments_avg_votes')
    ->get();
```